# trouble running the WFP msdn sample

Tags: sample, msdn, wfp

I am having trouble running the wfp sample from msdn.
I have followed the instructions on msdn site, and after I have entered "net start inspect" in the cmd I dont know what I suppose to see.
in visual it still says 'waiting to reconnect' .
I am new to this WFP api and im trying to learn it through this sapmle.
thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 'inspect' sample?  First, if you run this with vs 2013 and vmware, the 'waiting to reconnect' is alright signal.  You have to pause the debugging one time and restart debugging not stop.  And right click driver file in vmaware(target machine) and install it.  After that execute cmd with super right, type 'net start inspect'.  It's all.  IF you type DbgPrint("hello"); in code, you can see "hello" in vs2013 WinDbg.